# The index entry exceeds the maximum length

Tags: search, error, sql

I have been receiving this error:

> The index entry of length <> bytes for the index '<>' exceeds the
>   maximum length of <> bytes. The index entry of length for the index
>   exceeds maximum length in SQL which is 900 byte max. Content crawling
>   may not complete due to this issue and you will see crawling errors

I found a blog post which states the source is that the '**MSSDOCProps**' table has a column with a limit of *450 characters*, in unicode that 2 bytes per character so 900 bytes. The issue is that when including the '**PID**' which is 4 bytes, you get a size of 904 bytes.

( http://www.sharepointmcm.com/post/2011/07/05/A-Search-SQL-Index-Issue.aspx )

The workaround is to limit the `"MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex" property to 448`

( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.managedproperty.maxcharactersinpropertystoreindex.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 )

So I understand all that, but I'm not sure where exactly I would set this parameter. In the code-behind my Master Page?

I am using C#. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the value you want is here:

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.property.MaxCharactersInPropertyStoreIndex = 448;
```

Comment: Is this something I would only have to run once? or should I be setting it everytime a page load is done in SharePoint? I'm just not sure when/where to set this property.

Comment: This would have to be set each instance it is called, it would go into a custom webpart for the search. Sorry for the late reply  I didn't get the notification.

Comment: No problem. I was worried that I would have to set it each instance. Right now my master page has a SearchBoxEX control, which points to a webpage that has a Search Core Results webpart that is displaying the results. Perhaps it is possible to create a custom webpart inheriting its class. Do you know in what event I would have to set that property?

Comment: First off, incase you don't know how to extend webparts http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevennicolaou/archive/2010/06/24/extend-the-search-box-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx not sure on the function, but when you do that you will be able to see what you override. It should be fairly obvious.